# how to fetch data from one row with the samename

Tags: sql

I want to display jules is in lastname but 3 times after inputed in lname and I want display it all those 3 times.

I have tried this:

```
$result= mysqli_query($db,"select * from uploadedproduct where lastname='$lname'");
SELECT * FROM uploadedproduct WHERE lastname IN (SELECT *
                        FROM (SELECT lastname FROM uploadedproduct
                              GROUP BY lastname
                              HAVING COUNT(lastname) > 1)
                        AS a);
```

I'm getting this error:

> user not found

Answer (score 0):

Data from one row with samename can be fetched with using **distinct** and one select query is enough in nested query

```
SELECT distinct *  FROM uploadedproduct WHERE lastname IN (
                SELECT  lastname FROM uploadedproduct GROUP BY lastname HAVING 
                COUNT(lastname) > 1
      )
```

Comment: i also tried to edit them because i want lastname to be fetched after is inputted if exist it will display so i tried it like this

Comment: SELECT distinct *  FROM uploadedproduct WHERE lastname='$lname' IN (SELECT  lastname FROM uploadedproduct GROUP BY lastname HAVING  COUNT(lastname) > 1

Comment: but also refused please help me

Comment: Can you try following ?  SELECT distinct * FROM uploadedproduct WHERE lastname IN (SELECT lastname FROM uploadedproduct  where lastname='$lname' GROUP BY lastname HAVING COUNT(lastname) > 1 )